# aws datapipeline start stop ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-data-pipeline

this example: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/
does not seem to work. I followed the example and the pipeline is always canceled. There are no logs created, i did set up logging. the only "error message" i could find is.
Error MessageUnable to create resource for @Ec2Instance_2017-06-07T09:58:49 due to: No subnets found for the default VPC 'vpc-f7dxxxx'. Please specify a subnet. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingInput; Request ID: ebeeae6d-9537-4627-8a56-e832999a1940)

All i am trying to do is execute a aws ec2 start-instances aws cli command as outlined in the example. the instances do exist, they are in a "stopped" state. Has anyone been successful in setting up a pipeline to start and stop existing instances? How did you do it? Thanks for the help

Comment: I may have found the problem. I will reply back once the pipeline runs. It seems amazon left out an importance piece of information, setup the ec2 instance that runs the aws command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that was it. after you finish going through the example you need to look at the pipeline and edit it. Look for the EC2Resource area. Click on it. then add a subnet. place the micro instance in the same subnet as the ec2 instances you need to start or stop. The example does not address this